# Cordova downloaded html file not accessible with VKwebview iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Using the contentsync plugin, I am downloading html from my server.
The files are downloaded and I get the save path etc.

When trying to load the html into a div using jquery, VKwebview does not allow the loading of file://path_to_resource. There is no error, the view is just blank.

On an android device, the code works so I am fairly certain that it is the VKwebview

function startSync() {

```
var sync = ContentSync.sync({ src: imageZip, id: 'kittenZip' });

sync.on('progress', function(data) {
    imageDiv.innerHTML = "<p>Syncing images: "+data.progress + "%</p>";
});

sync.on('complete', function(data) {
    console.log(data.localPath);
    $('#html_div').load("file://" + data.localPath + "/index.html") 
}
    
});

sync.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e.message);
    // e.message
});

sync.on('cancel', function() {
    // triggered if event is cancelled
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [cordova-plugin-ios-xhr](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) and set your preferences to

```
 <preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
 <preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

This should solve the `file://` issue

Comment: The issue with these is that the plugins all show up an error that they are not in the NPM registry so I cant try them. I have tried manually adding them to the config, but installation fails

Comment: Did you do  cordova plugin add @globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr ?

Comment: It seems like ios 6 allows the installation of the plugin, but then contentsync plugin fails.

Comment: Fails how? What's the error ???

Comment: There was no error message visible. Once I reinstalled the contentsync plugin I was unable to get the ios_xhr plugin to work.   I am going to mark your answer as correct because that does appear to the answer to my problem. The installation issue is separate as I believe.